# Using ib_sync to get many live stock quotes using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a list to get a bunch of live stock quotes from Interactive Brokers. Here is my full code:

```
from ib_insync import * #Import all classes
util.startLoop() #Use when using jupyter notebooks
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496)

stocks = ['SPY','ANGL','GDX','TMV']

test = list()
for stock in stocks:
    stock = Stock(stock, 'SMART','USD')
    contract = ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
    test.append(ib.reqMktData(contract[0],snapshot=True))
    ib.sleep(1)
for stock in test:
    print(stock.last)
```

I get this error:

> NameError: name 'Stock' is not defined

Comment: What do you expect that line of code to do? It's like you have code that expects an object `Stock` to be defined, but there's no definition for it in your code. Did you copy and paste the code from elsewhere without knowing how it worked or something like that? Also, the indentation is totally off.

Comment: it should append each stock to the list(). I suppose I could do it individually for each stock to make it less complex.

Comment: Stock is a IB function, I believe that is part of the ib_sync import. I will double check that though

Comment: In that case it should just work. Maybe you have the wrong version of that library installed?

Comment: Stock('MSFT', 'SMART', 'USD', primaryExchange='NASDAQ')  should get MSFT stock. https://groups.io/g/insync/topic/6061586

Comment: yes there's a chance it could be a version issue. I suppose, I will try on a different computer that has different versions installed